# Get ip of consumers who connected to IBM MQ queue by PCF request from Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I know that MQExplorer GUI could show who connected to some queue by some channel and other information about this connection, but I didn't find anything in PCF to do that from Java.

Thanks in advance for commands and examples if they exist!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shows sample snippet shows how to retrieve the `conname`.

```
// Create the PCF message type for the inquire.
PCFMessage pcfCmd = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_STATUS);
// Add queue name
pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, "MYQ");
// We want Q HANDLE attributes
pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_Q_STATUS_TYPE, MQConstants.MQIACF_Q_HANDLE);
// We want to retrieve only the connection name
pcfCmd.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_Q_STATUS_ATTRS, MQConstants.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME);
// Execute the command. The returned object is an array of PCF messages.
PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = pcfCM.agent.send(pcfCmd);

try{
    for(int i = 0; i < pcfResponse.length;i++){
        String name = (String) pcfResponse[i].getParameterValue(MQConstants.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME);
        System.out.println("Connection Name: " + name);         
        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.print(ex);
}
```

You can modify the snippet per your need. Hope it helps.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much =)
Strange, I tried same before, but got an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in MQ Explorer is the MQSC command:

```
DISPLAY QSTATUS(<QName>) TYPE(HANDLE)
```

So, you need to look up the equivalent PCF command.